# What is this code means? fopen (pthis -> fname,w)

Tags: c, fopen

```
fp = fopen(pthis->fname,"w");
```

Well I, ask here second time.

I used that code.

Since I knew about that code, i always used fopen("C:\temp\kmj12134.txt","w")

This code means save the kmj12134.txt in C:\temp.

But when i use that code,

I don't know what is the file name and where is save place.

Do you know the file name and where is save place?

And do you know how to change file name and change save place?

Comment: The pointer to the filename is here: `pthis->fname`. You probably lack the most basic knowledge of C programming, or just programming. Start reading your C text book.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `fopen` [reference documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm). You will see the function is defined this way:

```
FILE * fopen ( const char * filename, const char * mode );
```

Your filename `"C:\temp\kmj12134.txt"` is the path to the file to either write (`w`) or read (`r`) depending on the `mode` option.

So `fp = fopen(pthis->fname,"w");` basically means you write a file at the path `pthis->fname` where `pthis->fname` is of type `const char*`. You can see this path by simply printing it:

```
printf("filename: %s\n", pthis->fname);
```

Comment: Consider linking to a [C reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm) of `fopen` instead of a `C++` one.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Even better:  [http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3).